# Why is there two identical method in laravel message bag?

Tags: laravel

I was reading `laravel` documentation regarding `messagebag`. There I found `any()` and `isNotEmpty()` methods. Both of them does the exact same thing. They try to determine if there are any messages and return true if there are any. I went to see the source code and I found that `isNotEmpty()` is doing nothing but calling the `any()` method.

```
public function isNotEmpty()
{
    return $this->any();
}

public function any()
{
    return $this->count() > 0;
}
```

What I don't understand is why `laravel` does same things in two places? Shouldn't one method be sufficient for this job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that one of the two methods would be sufficient. There is also not a single reason both of these methods exist, but I guess the combination of the following (and possibly even more) is why we have them:

- The `any()` method has been there long before `isNotEmpty()` and there has always been an `isEmpty()` method alongside `any()` (as inverse method).
- Because `isNotEmpty()` is a more obvious method name than `any()`, it has been added some years ago.
- For backwards compatibility and because the implementation of `any()` is really trivial, there has never been a good reason to remove `any()`.

It is actually quite common for programming languages and libraries to have different methods for the same thing. Some languages are using it more often and more obvious than others, but I guess it has a lot to do with readability. Although `isNotEmpty()` as in `if ($messages->isNotEmpty()) { ... }` is a lot longer than `if ($messages->any()) { ... }`, it seems more readable and understandable to me. But not everyone sees it the same way and my best guess is that there is a fan of `any()` in the group of the framework maintainers who doesn't want to write more than necessary.